# Incremental crawl still running during continous crawl

Tags: crawl, incremental-crawl

I have continuous crawl running on 2013 and everything I've read says that incremental crawl doesn't run if continuous crawl is selected but my crawl logs say different. Am I misunderstanding?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Answered my own question by reading this a little closer:
A continuous crawl does not process or retry items that return errors more than three times. **A "clean-up" incremental crawl automatically runs every four hours** for content sources that have continuous crawl enabled to re-crawl any items that repeatedly return errors. This incremental crawl will try to crawl the item again and then will postpone retries if the error persists.

Source: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219802.aspx